# SQL - how can I efficiently select multiple closest time series data points

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table `data` to record a stream of data with columns `recorded_at` DateTime and `value` Integer. The data is not distributed at regular intervals, there may be multiple rows per minute, or none for hours.

If I want to select a single value this query works great for my purposes, selecting the closest result greater than where I'm searching:

`select * from data where recorded_at > '2015-01-01 01:01:01' limit 1`

However, I can't find an efficient way to select the single closest row to multiple search dates aside from using a union of the above query repeated, which creates an enormous query if I want to select several hundred points. For example, if I wanted the single row closest to '2015-01-01 01:01:01' and also '2015-02-02 02:02:02'.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Basically the pseudo-query I'm after is:

`select * from data where recorded_at NEAR (date1, date2, date3)`
where NEAR works like IN but fuzzier, because I don't know the exact dates beforehand.

Comment: So what you want is `n` closest results rather than just 1?

Comment: no, I'm after the 1 closest result to N different search dates, I will clarify the question.

Comment: Say you have 6 dates in the table with `recorded_at` values (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7) and you need the date closest to 2 and 6. What should the result be?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: I'm asking how the `NEAR` should work. Should it return just  1 record that is nearest to ALL of the dates, or should it return 1 record PER DATE, each record being closest to a date provided in the set?

Comment: one record per date, each being closest to that date

Comment: Does [this work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32157342/1492578) then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get multiple points:

```
select d.* 
from data d
where recorded_at > '2015-01-01 01:01:01'
order by recorded_at
limit 100
```

To get them efficiently, create an index on `data(recorded_at)`:

```
create index idx_data_recorded_at on data(recorded_at);
```

Also, a `union` would probably *not* help your cause.  Although `limit` without an `order by` is not guaranteed to return any particular row, it would generally return the same row, over and over.

EDIT (based on question edit):

For multiple dates, this gets a bit harder.  You are probably best off using `union all`:

```
(select d.* 
 from data d
 where recorded_at > '2015-01-01 01:01:01'
 order by recorded_at
 limit 1
) union all
(select d.* 
 from data d
 where recorded_at > '2015-02-01 01:01:01'
 order by recorded_at
 limit 1
)
```

Although complicated, each subquery should be blazingly fast with the right index so the overall query should be quite fast.

Comment: The union is where I'm at now, but if I want to find the nearest row to 100 dates, the query gets large (or I need to make 100 separate queries, which is slower over the wire).

Comment: @EJ01 . . . It is one query that you are issuing, not 100.  One single query with 100 subqueries.

Comment: Yes, with the union it's one query, and it is quite fast, I'm just concerned about the query itself getting too large (for example if I try to select 1000 dates worth). Perhaps I'm attempting to over-optimize this.

Comment: @EJ01 . . . 1,000 dates would be a lot of days.

Answer (score 1):

You need ORDER by

```
select * from data 
where recorded_at > '2015-01-01 01:01:01' and recorded_at < '2015-01-02 01:01:01' 
order by recorded_at limit 1
```

This is edited after OP edited his question

If you want to have multiple dates and want to get closest dates for each of these, I would suggest using a lookup table that has all your searched dates and try the following. keycol is the unique column in table data

```
select t1.* from
(
select t.keycol,min(t.recorded_at) as recorded_at from data as t inner join
lookup_table as dates on t.recorded_at>look.recorded_at
group by t.keycol
) as t2 on t1.keycol=t2.keycol and t1.recorded_at=t2.recorded_at
```

Comment: replace "limit 1" by "limit 100" to get the 100 closest data points > 2015-01-01 01:01:01

Comment: I edited my question slightly. I'm only after the single row closest to multiple search dates, so for example the closest row to '2015-01-01' and the closest row to '2015-02-02'.

Comment: I'm not looking for the rows between two dates, I'm looking for the individual rows closest to a list of search dates. Basically a way to repeat my example of the single-query without having to execute that query many times.

Answer (score 0):

The following query selects a date closest to each of the dates:

```
select d1.recorded_at rec_at, d2.recorded_at closest, min(d2.recorded_at - d1.recorded_at) difference
from data d1, data d2
where d1.recorded_at in ('2015-01-01 01:01:01', '2015-02-01 01:01:01', ...)
      and d2.recorded_at > d1.recorded_at
group by d1.recorded_at
```

Comment: If I pick a date from a row for the IN section, it will return results, but not if I choose dates that are close to it.